# Neo4j : Passing Relationship as a query parameter

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created the following query which works fine when i am passing all the relationship.

```
@Query(value="START profile=node(*) "
                + "MATCH profile - [rel:create | stream | like | follow] - feeds "
                + "WHERE profile.id ={profileId} "
                + "WITH distinct feeds as feed, rel.date as date "
                + "ORDER BY date DESC "
                + "RETURN DISTINCT feed;")
    public List<Feed> findByProfileId(@Param("profileId") String profileId);
```

but i want to fetch data for specific action like the query below

```
@Query(value="START profile=node(*) "
                + "MATCH profile - [rel:{action}] - feeds "
                + "WHERE profile.id ={profileId} "
                + "WITH distinct feeds as feed, rel.date as date "
                + "ORDER BY date DESC "
                + "RETURN DISTINCT feed;")
public List<Feed> findByProfileId(@Param("action") String action,@Param("profileId") String profileId);
```

But this does not work and i get the following error.

```
org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResult Exception: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or an identifier
```

I think this is not a correct way to pass param in relationship. 
Is there a way how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you should not use `start n=node(*)` in your query
   use a label like `:Profile` and an index/unique constraint on `:Profile(id)`

   MATCH (profile:Profile) WHERE profile.id = {profileId}
2. you can't use rel-types as parameters directly but you can check the type of your relationship, e.g. against a set of names that is passed in

either

```
WHERE type(rel) = {action}
```

or

```
WHERE type(rel) IN {actions}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way currently to pass relationship types nor labels as query parameters.

You will need to handle it in your application, when building the query string.

Here is a simple example in PHP :

```
$relTypes = array(':FACEBOOK_PROFILE',':TWITTER_PROFILE');
$relString = implode('|', $relTypes);
$q = 'MATCH (n:User)-['.$relString.']->(profile)';
```